# XHR HTTP Authorization Username/Password Character Limit

Tags: php, authorization, titanium, xmlhttprequest

If I send more than 50 characters through XHR the username/password come through empty with `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`.

Is this a known limitation? Are there any workarounds?